# How to play raw pcm data in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, sdk, pcm

I am developing an application for voice chat. Now I want to play raw pcm audio data in iPhone. I could not achieve it. Can anyone help me to play pcm data?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to read up on Audio Queue Services:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html